# Fill database with dummy data

Tags: mysql

I have built a tool which will auto generates a rest layer for each table in a database. Now I am looking for an option to auto generate sample data in these tables to perform automated tests.

Comment: Obviously, we can't give you an exact answer, because you have provided no table structure or description of what this data would look like.

Comment: Best way is to define constructor for each test file. in that constructor add test data and in de-structor remove that dummy data.